# Implement menu in fragment in Android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, menuitem

I want to implement menu in fragment class. The fragment works fine and there is not error but there is no menu shown in the fragment. I am implementing the class in the following way

```
public class FilesFragment extends Fragment {

    public FilesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_files, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.files_menu,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_setting){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"setting clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

and this is the xml file of files_menu in menu folder.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:title="settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/aobut"
        android:title="About"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

</menu>
```

The above code is not showing the menu at all. How do menu is implemented in the fragment?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can populate the menu in any view without any complexity. Use the following code and enjoy.

any View can be a button , imageView or any other else in which you want to inflate this menu. No need to add menu in xml. Just do in java

```
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, any View);
    popup.inflate(R.menu.files_menu );
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {


        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_setting) {
            // do stuff
        } else if (id == R.id.aobut) {
            //

        } 


        return true;
    });
    popup.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I have two fragments and i want to implement this is in fragment_two how would it implement in that fragment?

Comment: Can you add the screen shot of that screen?

Comment: This is what I want, different menu for different fragments. The above code is for Tab TWO in which the title, toolbar are showing correctly but the menu is not showing.

Comment: You can make an image view containing menu icon above on toolbar. Then inflate menu in that imageview in your activity which is containing the toolbar. and when you change the fragment also change the menu in popup.inflate() function